# How to add structure of folder and documents to a MonoDevelop project?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a hierarchy of folders and source files here and would like to add everything to a MonoDevelop MT project. I'm failing miserably. "Add files" only allows files and no folders, drag & drop does not do anything.

What's your way of dealing with this task?
René

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 features that make this easier:

1) Right-click on the project and select "Display Options"->"Show all files". You can then right-click on files that aren't in the project and choose "Include in project".

2) In Project Options, enable "Search for new files on load", then reload the project.

In MonoDevelop 2.6, which has not yet been released, we have an "Add files from folder" command that recursively searches a folder structure and lets you select which files to add.

Comment: "Show all files" made my day! Thanks!

Comment: The option doesn't seem to do anything on Monodevelop 3.0.3.2, even if you also select "Automatically include found files".

Answer (score 0):

Yup, i have not found a workarround but what i do its just create the folder structure and add the files to each folder.

Hope this helps

Alex